# Meteor Error: write after end

Tags: mongodb, nginx, meteor

**EDIT**
It seems that the second server DOES occasionally get this error, this makes me near certain it's a config problem. Could it be one of:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 2
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse =1
```

version information as requested: `Meteor: 1.5.0
OS: Ubuntu 16.04
Provider: AWS EC2`

I'm getting the following error, intermittently and seemingly randomly, on both processes running on one server (of a pair). The other server never gets this error, the error doesn't refer to any code I've written, so I can only assume its (a) a bug in Meteor or (b), a bug with my server config. The server whose processes are crashing is also hosting two other meteor sites, both of which occasionally get this error:

```
Error: write after end
at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:167:12)
at PassThrough.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:212:5)
at IncomingMessage.ondata (_stream_readable.js:542:20)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:169:7)
at IncomingMessage.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:368:10)
at flow (_stream_readable.js:759:26)
at resume_ (_stream_readable.js:739:3)
at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:511:9)
at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:466:17)
```

things I've already checked:

1. memory limits (nowhere near close)
2. connection limits - very small, around 20 per server at the time of failure, and the processes were bumped to the second server within 1 minute, which handled them + it's own just fine
3. process limits - both processes on server 1 failed within 7 minutes of each other.
4. server config - while I was trying to eek out a little extra performance during load testing, I modified `sysctl.conf` based on a post I saw for high load node.js servers, this is the contents of the faulty servers `sysctl.conf` however, the functioning server has an identical config.

.

```
fs.file-max = 1000000
fs.nr_open = 1000000
ifs.file-max = 70000
net.nf_conntrack_max = 1048576
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max = 32768
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 2
net.ipv4.tcp_max_orphans = 8192
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 16768    61000
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 10024
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 360000
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 2500
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65535
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse =1
net.core.somaxconn = 20048
```

I have an NGINX balancer on server1 which load balances across the 4 processes (2 per server). The NGINX error log is littered with lines as follows:

`2017/08/17 16:15:01 [warn] 1221#1221: *6233472 an upstream response is buffered to a temporary file /var/lib/nginx/proxy/1/46/0000029461 while reading upstream, client: 164.68.80.47, server: server redacted, request: "GET path redacted HTTP/1.1", upstream: "path redacted", host: "host redacted", referrer: "referrer redacted"`

At the time of the error, I see a pair of lines like this:

`2017/08/17 15:07:19 [error] 1222#1222: *6215301 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: ip redacted, server: server redacted, request: "GET /admin/sockjs/info?cb=o2ziavvsua HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin/sockjs/info?cb=o2ziavvsua", host: "hostname redacted", referrer: "referrer redacted"`

`2017/08/17 15:07:19 [warn] 1222#1222: *6215301 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: ip redacted, server: server redacted, request: "GET /admin/sockjs/info?cb=o2ziavvsua HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin/sockjs/info?cb=o2ziavvsua", host: "hostname redacted", referrer: "referrer redacted"`

If it matters at all, I'm using a 3 node mongo replica set, where both servers are pointing at all 3 nodes.

I'm also using a custom hosted version of kadira (since it went offline).

If there is no way to stop the errors, is there anyway to stop them taking down the entire process, there are times when 50-100 users are connected per process, booting them all because of one error seems excessive

Comment: You should also specify Meteor/OS/etc versions

Comment: @Styx question edited, thanks

Comment: I'd recommend to update Meteor to `1.5.1`, just to be sure, you know.

Answer (score 0):

It's been two days without a crash, so I think the solution was changing:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 2
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
```

to

```
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 15
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 0
```

I don't know which of those was causing the problem (probably the timeout). I still think its a "bug" that a single "Write after end" error crashes the entire meteor process. Perhaps this should simply be logged.